# How to find if a secret word contains all the characters from a list?

Tags: python, string, list, function

I have been trying to solve this problem because it is a part of constructing Hangman game.

My problem is that I need to write a code which would check if all the list items are in the secret word. If all are in a list, it will return True, if not, False.

This is my work I have done:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    a_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(lettersGuessed)):

        a_list.append(lettersGuessed[i])
    str1 = ''.join(a_list)
    if str1 in secretWord:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

isWordGuessed('apple', ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's'])
```

However, I have tried to do this:

isWordGuessed('apple', ['a', 'p', 'l', 'p', 'e'])

It returns False, even though all letters in a list are in 'apple'

I guess I could solve this without making a string but I don't how. By the way, this must work for any word and list given. If all list items are in a word, it is true, otherwise false...Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you're not asking the wrong question? The word is guessed if no letter in it remains unguessed, not if all the guesses are correct -- modulo not being wrong too many times. Probably why many people give answers that answer your direct question but wouldn't help solve the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would convert the secret word and the already guessed letters both to sets and check whether the set of the characters of the secret word is a subset of the set of the guessed characters:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    return set(secretWord) <= set(lettersGuessed)
```

Comment: Best answer, but it should be: (`<=`, i.e. `set(secretWord) <= set(lettersGuessed)` to include the perfect guess case.

Comment: isWordGuessed('apple', ['a', 'p', 'l', 'e']), it returns False. All letters are in secret word 'apple'. The idea is that if the word has the same letter more than once, it must count towards the guessed word. _pp__  -> apple ? or is it not?

Comment: @PedroRomano You are right :) Thank you for noting that, I edited the answer

Comment: @user1692479 You are welcome. I did it wrong at the beginning because of always typing too fast at stackoverflow and the lack of testing:)